# Is it ok if everything is looking ok but X/HTML and CSS are not valid , for CMS's Admin/control panel?

Tags: css, xhtml, w3c, web-standards, w3c-validation

Is it OK if everything looking OK but HTML and CSS are not valid , for CMS Admin/control panel?

Should we only consider Web-standards for site, not necessary for site-management tools?

for example

- :http://example.com/wp-admin
- :http://example.com/admin/

Comment: Note that example.com, example.net and example.org are canonically and by standard used for adress examples. The poor holder of site.com will now probably receive a lot of visitor-noise and prolly much spam because of you. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com .

Comment: @presnel, that is exactly what the domain name is for: *"By implementing the reservation, the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) made available domains to use in technical and software documentation, manuals and sample software configurations. Thus, documentation writers can be sure to select a domain name without creating naming conflicts if end-users try to use the sample configurations or examples verbatim."*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the point of standards compliance is to make everything work correctly for every user. Even though admin areas are only accessible to a few select users per site, if you are building a CMS you have to consider that many, many people might use your script which would add additional users who will be needing to access those admin panels. It's best to make everything standards compliant, that's why they create them. If an admin can't get the admin panel working properly, they'll ditch the script.

Comment: My question is "i mean after making all things from . i tested everything is working fine but XHTML and CSS many validation errors. Should i invest time to solve them."

Answer (score 1):

I agree it may not be worthwhile to to make everything valid.  As long as you've done your testing and it working then it's probably not worth the time to make everything valid.

Answer (score -2):

Some validation errors matter, some don't.  The spec is a bit ridiculous in its requirements in places.  What is important is that all open tags are closed and they are nested correctly as if this is not done there can be many subtle errors both now and in the future.  As for non-encoded entities, using rel's and targets when you shouldn't - it doesn't matter so much.

Since you (usually) can control the access to the admin area (rather than normally having every single device and platform access it) it certainly matters less.  The time would probably be better spent adding more features and fixing real bugs rather than aiming for 100% compliance. Don't tell any standards advocates I said that though.  :)